# Is it possible to make groups based on an ID of a person in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, group

I have this data:

```
data <- data.frame(id_pers=c(4102,13102,27101,27102,28101,28102, 42101,42102,56102,73102,74103,103104,117103,117104,117105),
                   birthyear=c(1992,1994,1993,1992,1995,1999,2000,2001,2000, 1994, 1999, 1978, 1986, 1998, 1999))
```

I want to group the different persons by familys in a new column, so that persons 27101,27102 (siblings) are group/family 1 and 42101,42102 are in group 2, 117103,117104,117105 are in group 3 so on.
Person "4102" has no siblings and should be a NA in the new column.
It is always the case that 2 or more persons are siblings if the ID's are not further apart than a maximum of 6 numbers.
I have a far larger dataset with over 3000 rows. How could I do it the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `round` with `digits = -1` (or -2) if you have `id_pers` that goes above 10 observations per family. If you want the id to be integers from 1; you can use `cur_group_id`:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(fam_id = round(id_pers - 5, digits = -1)) %>% 
  mutate(fam_gp = cur_group_id())
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 15 × 3
# Groups:   fam_id [10]
   id_pers birthyear fam_id fam_gp
     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>
 1    4102      1992   4100      1
 2   13102      1994  13100      2
 3   27101      1993  27100      3
 4   27102      1992  27100      3
 5   28101      1995  28100      4
 6   28106      1999  28100      4
 7   42101      2000  42100      5
 8   42102      2001  42100      5
 9   56102      2000  56100      6
10   73102      1994  73100      7
11   74103      1999  74100      8
12  103104      1978 103100      9
13  117103      1986 117100     10
14  117104      1998 117100     10
15  117105      1999 117100     10
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we can the 1000s digit (and above) to delineate groups.

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(
    famgroup = trunc(id_pers/1000),
    famgroup = match(famgroup, unique(famgroup))
  )
#    id_pers birthyear famgroup
# 1     4102      1992        1
# 2    13102      1994        2
# 3    27101      1993        3
# 4    27102      1992        3
# 5    28101      1995        4
# 6    28102      1999        4
# 7    42101      2000        5
# 8    42102      2001        5
# 9    56102      2000        6
# 10   73102      1994        7
# 11   74103      1999        8
# 12  103104      1978        9
# 13  117103      1986       10
# 14  117104      1998       10
# 15  117105      1999       10
```